# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency with Useeffect hook. Is it bad practice to ignore this warning?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a use effect to verify if two passwords are equal. I want to only run if the confirm_pw state changes, not if the password state changes.

I've accomplished this with

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (password !== confirm_pw) {
      setPasswordMismatchErr(true);
    } else {
      setPasswordMismatchErr(false);
    }
  }, [confirm_pw])
```

This works exactly as expected! However, react keeps telling me

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'password'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

Should I ignore this warning? Is there some way to change the code and keep the desired result?

Password and confirm_pw are defined as:

```js
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [confirm_pw, setConfirmPW] = useState("");
```

and used

```
<input
            className="box__input"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={handlePassword}
            type="password"
            required
          />
<input
            className="box__input"
            name="confirm_pw"
            value={confirm_pw}
            type="password"
            onChange={handleConfirmPassword}
            required
          />
```

Handleconfirmpassword and handlePassword are simple wrappers around the setstate functions.

Comment: I updated the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linter is correct. Your current code has a bug: what if the user is *sure* they typed in the confirm password correctly, and need to re-type the password in the first input? Then, after making changes, despite having both password boxes match, `passwordMismatchErr` will remain `true`.

Add `password` to the dependency array:

```
}, [password, confirm_pw])
```

and then, for `passwordMismatchErr`, to keep it from being displayed when the user is initially typing, check whether `confirm_pw` is empty or not first. Eg:

```
{
  passwordMismatchErr && confirm_pw ? <div>Error...</div> : null
}
```

You can also simplify the `useEffect` callback with:

```
setPasswordMismatchErr(password !== confirm_pw);
```